# Press back button Android automation - Python

Tags: android, python, automation, back

How to press back in Python on Android device?
What I currently got is not in Python and wont work.

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidKeyCode
       self.driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK)
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using simply:

```
self.driver.back()
```

or

```
self.driver.press_keycode(4)
```

and it works for me. You don't have to import any special lib.
Here is [documentation](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/back/)